# uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'split' of undefined error for below code
Can anyone please help why I'm getting this . thanks

```
$("#registration_date1, #registration_date2, #last_login1, #last_login2, #expiry_date, #status, #role," +

        " div#userTable_filter :input").bind("keyup change", function () {

    var userIds = [];
    var data = $('#userTable').dataTable().fnSettings().aiDisplay;
    var allData = $('#userTable').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData;

    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        var url = allData[val]._aData[allData[val]._aData.length - 1];
        var userId = url.split('/')[3].split('"')[0];
        userIds.push(userId);
    });
```

Comment: Does your `url` always have 3+ occurrences of `/`? You're doing `url.split('/')[3]` without first checking if the array has four items, so perhaps the item you're trying to grab does not exist.

Comment: yea cl `userId`. also note that arrays are 0-based.

Answer (score -1):

```
var allData = $('#userTable').dataTable().fnSettings().aoData;
```

At this line, are you sure you need `.aoData`? Because it seems that everywhere else you've used `.aData` array. Check the spelling.

Comment: He's not calling `.split()` on `allData`. And I don't see any uses of `.aData` anywhere in the script.

Comment: @Bamar `.aoData` was used in `allData` which was then used in `url` which then was `.split()`-ed

Comment: If `.aoData` is wrong, then the error would complain about trying to use `.allData[val]`, which is the line before the call to `.split()`.

Comment: Anyway, your question should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Bamar you're right. My question should have been a comment. But those are only allowed above 50 reputation. So that was the only way, I am sorry...

Comment: The point of the restriction is to make sure you learn the rules before you start commenting. Breaking the rules is not the way to do that.